# Link de um Iframe abrindo em nova aba?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Existe a possibilidade de quando a pessoa clicar em um link em um `iframe`, esse link abrir em outra aba?

Não tenho controle do HTML da outra página, por isso não consigo colocar o `_blank` no link pelo HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Se as páginas estiverem no mesmo domínio:

Sim, é possível. Basta adicionar o `target="_blank"` em todos os links. Exemplo com jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("iframe").load(function () {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe")
        var anchors = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i in anchors) {
            anchors[i].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        }
    });
});
```

### Se estiverem em domínios diferentes:

Não é possível manipular a página devido à [política de segurança de mesma origem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem).

No entanto dá pra fazer uma gambiarra, criando um proxy que disponibilize um espelho da página original no seu domínio. Isso só pode ser feito com linguagens server-side.

Comment: Olá @[rodorgas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6267/rodorgas), só pra agregar conteúdo à sua resposta, esse caso de *politica de mesma origem* não só se refere à situações de domínios iguais, existem outros critérios que são analisados, vale dar uma olhada nesse [conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/361278/como-identifcar-se-um-link-foi-aberto-por-um-iframe-em-uma-nova-guia/362242#362242).