# Como identifcar se um link foi aberto por um iframe em uma nova guia?

Tags: javascript

Como identificar se qualquer link originado de um `iframe` que não tenho acesso foi aberto em uma nova guia?

Tentei com `document.getElementById("i").addEventListener("click", a);`, mas ao que percebi não é possível usar `onclick` em um `iframe` ao menos que tenha acesso direto ao código fonte do `iframe`

Tentei com uma `div` sobreposta porém anula o primeiro click no `iframe` sendo que é necessário mais de um click para abrir o link

Então procurei como identificar se um link foi aberto em uma nova guia e não achei nada parecido.

O usuario da minha pagina tem que completar uma tarefa no `iframe` ao terminar a tarefa dentro do `iframe` uma pagina será aberta em nova guia, como identificar se a guia foi aberta?

Snippet de exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("i").onclick = function a(){
console.log("ok")
}
```

```html
Preencha com seu nome e conclua<br>
<iframe id="i" src="https://editor.sollic.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

---

O mais proximo que cheguei foi por meio de uma `div` sobrepondo o `iframe`.

Pagina de exemplo: [https://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow](http://editor.sollic.com/stackoverflow)

**Explicando o código:**
Ao passar o mouse sobre a `div` ela desaparecerá por **1 segundo** sempre que o mouse estiver sobre ela permitindo que clique em qualquer lugar até que a pagina saia de foco, com isso se a `div` estiver oculta e a pagina sair de foco ativará o **"gatilho"** que enviará **"ok" no console** ou no caso do link de exemplo mudará a cor de fundo para vermelho.

> Porém há momentos que funciona corretamente e em outros não funciona
>   ou funciona de forma errada, como clicando em qualquer lugar e
>   recebendo a mensagem do console ou mudando a cor de fundo.
>   **O snippet não funciona corretamente pois o stackoverflow bloqueia.**

```js
var foco = true;

function con() { //função que será ativada ao passar o mouse
   window.onblur = function(){foco = false} //verifica se a pagina está fora de foco
   window.onfocus = function(){foco = true} //verifica se a pagina está em foco
   
   if(foco!=false) {document.getElementById("a").style.display='block'} //se a pagina estiver em foco reativa a div
   else {console.log("ok")} //se a pagina estiver em foco envia "ok" no console
}

function la() {document.getElementById("a").style.display='none'} //desativa a div
```

```css
#a{
position:absolute;
z-index:1;
background:#000;
width:304px;
height:155px
}
```

```html
<div id="a" onmouseover="setTimeout(con, 1000);la();"></div>
<iframe id="i" src="https://editor.sollic.com/iframe.html"></iframe>
```

Comment: Só uma curiosidade: que ação vc queria fazer ao detectar que a nova aba foi aberta?

Comment: No momento a pagina vai ser redirecionada para a pagina anterior

Comment: É jovem, sem querer ser desanimador, mas acho que isso não é possível. Um iframe é como se fosse um documento separado dentro de outro. O documento pai não escuta eventos no documento filho, a não ser que fosse do mesmo domínio. Quando o iframe abre uma nova aba, esse evento passa por cima do documento pai, e não cria nenhum tipo de relação entre o documento pai e o documento do iframe. O único evento que consigo ver que cria uma certa ligação entre os dois documentos é o `window.onblur`, já que, quando uma nova é aberta, o `blur` é disparado no documento da aba que estava ativa.

Comment: Porém o `blur` tb é disparado quando vc muda de aba, aí não tem como saber se o evento foi disparado por causa do iframe.

Comment: Eu imaginei que o blur seria assim, mas se eu tiver o endereço da pagina que vai ser aberta, é possível acessar pelo histórico do navegador se a pagina foi aberta?

Comment: Não tem como acessar o histórico via JS, até por motivos de segurança e privacidade. Já pensou uma página saber quais sites vc andou visitando?

Comment: @Sam eu fiz de outra maneira como está descrito na pergunta, porém nem sempre funciona e eu não consegui achar o que causa esse problema, seria o cache do navegador ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Pra mim vc deveria desistir disso. Não tem como funcionar, pelos motivos que descrevi acima. Vc nunca vai saber quando uma nova aba foi aberta pelo iframe.

Comment: ⚠️ Todas as respostas são boas, mas não são nada além do que eu comentei acima =]

Comment: @Sam realmente são, mas eu ofereci a recompensa para maneiras viáveis para fazer isso, como o meu código na pergunta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando o assunto se trata de `iFrames`, deve-se considerar um fator decisivo para o andamento do seu problema. A Politica da mesma origem(**SOP**). [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
[[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

> Um navegador da Web permite que scripts contidos em uma primeira
>   página acessem dados em uma segunda página da Web, mas somente se ambas as páginas da Web tiverem a mesma origem. [1]

**Mas como saber se estou usando um iFrame de *mesma origem* que minha página Web?**
Em comparação, duas URL's possuem *mesma origem* se o **protocolo**(*http*,*https*), **porta**(se for expecífica) and **host**(se forem iguais em ambos).

Vamos simular que o seu site possua a seguinte URL:

```
http://meusite.markvaaz.com/pasta/index.html:
```

```
|URL                                        | RESULTADO     | RAZÃO 
+-------------------------------------------+---------------+------------------------------+ 
|http://markvaaz.com/pasta/site.html        |  Mesma Origem | Apenas caminhos diferentes.  |
|http://markvaaz.com/pasta/pasta2/site2.html|  Mesma Origem | Apenas caminhos diferentes.  |
|https://markvaaz.com/pasta/html.html       |     Falha     | Protocolo diferente(https).  |
|http://markvaaz.com:81/pasta/outro.html    |     Falha     | Portas diferente da padrão.  |
|https://editor.sollic.com/iframe.html      |     Falha     | Protocolo/host diferentes .  |
```

**Nota¹**: O protocolo `http://` utiliza a porta 80 como padrão. 
**Nota²**: Para o [IE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) a diferença de portas não é validado, logo, seria considerado Mesma Origem no IE caso a URL acessada utilizasse outra porta.

Caso seu resultado for de *Mesma Origem*, você poderá utilizar [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) para trocar informações entre seus Objetos, segue um exemplo.

Na sua página principal:

```
window.onload = function(){
   var frame = document.getElementById('i'); 
   frame.contentWindow.postMessage('Olá Frame.', '*'); 
};
```

No seu iFrame:

```
    window.addEventListener('mensagem', function(e)){
    console.log('mensagem recebida!');
};
```

**É possível desabilitar a *Politica da mesma origem* do seu navegador?**
Há uma maneira de realizar a manipulação entre `frames`, porém, se tornaria inútil(mesmo achando válido explanar sobre o assunto) para o seu caso, uma vez que terceiros utilizarão seu Website. Desabilitar a *política da mesma origem* consiste em uma sequência de passos(podendo ser de simples até complicado dependendo de qual navegador deseja desabilitar o SOP) que afetará apenas o seu navegador e impedirá de que o mesmo cenário ocorra quando subir o seu servidor. Apesar de não ser indicado utilizar a desabilitação, indico fazer isso apenas para casos de testes e desenvolvimento, pois deixará seu navegador vulnerável para qualquer acesso de origens desconhecidas.

- [Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)
- [Mozilla Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088609/disable-firefox-same-origin-policy)
- [Apple Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556429/disabling-same-origin-policy-in-safari/38228168#38228168)
- Opera: não é possível.
- Microsoft Edge: não é possível.
- [Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947359/disable-same-origin-policy-internet-explorer).

Fontes:[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame/46072799),
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498831/refused-to-display-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-sameorigin),
[w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_frame.asp),
[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy),
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gejGOC__vQs).

Answer (score 7):

**Isso não pode ser feito** na maioria dos casos.

Essa impossibilidade é uma medida de segurança adotada para prevenir principalmente ameaças como o [XSS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). No entanto, se o `iframe`  tiver a mesma origem do seu site, você pode acessar o seu conteúdo e realizar as modificações.

No exemplo abaixo, o `iframe` não poderia ser modificado pelo JavaScript, já que as origens são **diferentes**:

```
<!-- Assuma que a URL do site é google.com: -->

<!-- O `iframe` a seguir NÃO poderia ser "acessado", já que a origem "apple.com" é diferente de "google.com": -->
<iframe src="https://apple.com"></iframe>
```

No exemplo a seguir, no entanto, o `iframe` poderia ser modificado, já que as origens são **iguais**:

```
<!-- Assuma que a URL do site é google.com: -->

<!-- O `iframe` a seguir poderia ser "acessado", já que as origens são iguais: -->
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow"></iframe>
```

Para acessar, você pode fazer assim:

```
//
// NOTA:
//
// Esse código só irá funcionar se você estiver em uma página
// cuja URL comece com "https://google.com"!
//

// Inserir um <iframe> na página:
document.body.innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=StackOverflow" style="width: 80vw; height: 60vh;"></iframe>'

// Capturar o elemento <iframe>:
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')

// Aguardar o conteúdo carregar:
iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Acessar o documento do <iframe>:
  const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument
    ? iframe.contentDocument
    : iframe.contentWindow.document

  // Colorir todos os links de vermelho para demonstração:
  iframeDocument.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a) => {
    a.style.setProperty('color', 'red')
  })
})
```

No exemplo acima (que para funcionar deve ser executado em alguma página cuja origem seja `google.com`), todos os links do `iframe` serão pintados de vermelho.

---

Em suma, a não ser que as origens sejam as mesmas, você não será capaz de identificar se o link foi aberto ou não, assumindo que ele esteja contido em um `iframe`.